# Merge a list of pandas dataframes WITH different column names each time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reduce

I have a list of dataframes with a respective column names to join so for example:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

col_join = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
```

I have seen answers using the reduce function in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on=["Col1"], how="outer"), dfs)
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

df1 Columns:

Data1 Dim1 Dim2 Dim3

df2 Columns:

Example1 Example2 Example3

df3 Columns:

Other1 Other2 Other3

df1 to df2 is joined by Dim1 to Example1.
df1 to df3 is joined by Dim2 to Other1.
This list goes until df(n) where n can be even 20 dataframes being joined to df1 on different column names.

My idea is to pass a function with the list of the original df1 and the remainder df2, df3, df4 ... dfn.

Other argument is the list of merging columns, like above for example it would be: left_on=["Dim1"], right_on=["Example1"].

Next would be, joining df1 (already including df2 in the join) to df3 on Dim2 and Other1.

Each dataframe will be joined to df1 on a different column, which may or may not share the same name as df1, that's why left and right are arguments that should be used.d

How to incorporate the fact that merging columns are changing at each join inside the reduce function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should provide a minimal example to illustrate your issue ;)

Comment: I just added more explanation. I hope it clarifies.

Comment: A minimal example with the expected output would have been more explicit than a long description

Answer (score 0):

This might work (untested):

```
result = df1
for df, col in zip(dfs[1:], col_join):
    result = pd.merge(result, df, on=[col], how='outer')
```